# UK Date converting to US date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a recurring issue where when a date is copied across worksheets it is converted from UK format to US format.  I created the below code which I am retrieving the D/M/Y and placing it into a string in the hope it would hardcode the correct date. However this is still converting into a US date.

Any help in ensuring the UK format date is held would be much appreciated.

```
Dim mydate As Date
Dim sDay As String
Dim sMonth As String
Dim sYear As String
Dim sYesterdayDate As String
Dim ws As Variant

mydate = wbRecFile.Sheets(1).Range("c2").value **Date in C2 = 07/02/2019
sDay = Format(mydate, "DD")
sMonth = Format(mydate, "MM")
sYear = Format(mydate, "YYYY")

sYesterdayDate = sDay & "/" & sMonth & "/" & sYear

wbRecFile.Activate

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With ws
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

ws.Range("C1:C" & lastrow).value = sYesterdayDate

Next ws
```

Comment: You are setting a string to the cell, and I assume the cell format is "General", in which case Excel is free to parse the value. Set the cells format to Date and store an actual date, not a string. If you are adamant you want to store dates as strings and in certain format (which you should not be), change cell format to "Text".

Comment: Try using `Dateserial` instead, and the `month` `year` `day` functions available

Comment: Could you please share what do you have and what do you want to have please?

Comment: What is actually in `wbRecFile.Sheets(1).Range("c2")`? Is it a real date or a string?  How did it get there?  If it is a `real date`, if you change the format to `General` you should see a 5 digit number.  What is that number?

Answer (score 1):

You're approaching this the wrong way. Excel stores dates as a numerical value that's independent from its display format, and if you try to sidestep this by storing dates as a string then you break the ability to perform calculations with those dates.

If you want to format a range as `dd/mm/yyyy`, set its `NumberFormat` to `"dd\/mm\/yyyy"` (if you omit the backslashes, you'll see hyphens instead of slashes). However, you'd be better off using the default date format which displays dates according to the user's system settings, since this will be the preferred format of whoever's interacting with your workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the datevalue from the cell usually works for me:

```
Dim mydate As Date
Dim ws As Variant

mydate = DateValue(wbRecFile.Sheets(1).Range("c2").value )

wbRecFile.Activate

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    With ws
        lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

ws.Range("C1:C" & lastrow).value = mydate

Next ws
```

Edit: applied my changes to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach is to convert the date in text and split it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Day As String, Month As String, Year As String
    Dim USFormat As String, UKFormat As String

    USFormat = "2019/02/20"

    Day = Right(USFormat, 2)
    Month = Mid(USFormat, 6, 2)
    Year = Left(USFormat, 4)

    UKFormat = Day & "/" & Month & "/" & Year

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like so, I've used in the past.  Prefer not to use any variable names that are close to key words, and use the dateserial.  Simlar in approach to @error 1004's

```
Function US_TO_UK(dtInput As Variant, Optional strDelim As String = "/") As Date

Dim aSegements() As String

aSegements = Split(dtInput, strDelim)

US_TO_UK = DateSerial(aSegements(0), aSegements(1), aSegements(2))

Erase aSegements

End Function
```